# How to password protect a network connected printer for Windows PCs?

Tags: networking, printing, printer

I am wondering if I can password protect a printer that is connected to the network. The printer, a Brother HL-L2360DW, it is connected to the network via Ethernet to a switch in the office, and distributed to the computers that are also connected via Ethernet to the switch.

When a user prints something to that printer, it is printed on "Security paper". I want to put a password on it so when someone clicks print, a dialog box shows up that states that a password is required.

The PCs in the clinic run Windows 10 Pro, and there is no Windows Server on the network.

Can this be done? I have seen a print server recommended, so could getting a Windows Server Specific OS help, or can it be done by connecting the printer to USB to a Windows 10 Pro machine used by the medical assistant and leaving it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have consulted your printer's
[Online User's Guide](https://support.brother.com/g/s/id/htmldoc/printer/cv_hll2300d/use/manual/index.html#GUID-FF66F538-CFCB-4BC5-925F-FB57F3BEA3AE_188)
and have found no such option in your printer's firmware.

The answer is then negative for network connect.

You may have more options when using a PC as a print server, but not when
the printer is directly available on the switch.